# Background scroll on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello, the website that I am currently working on is [Redec](https://www.redecindustrial.com/), and I am having an issue with the background scrolling when the menu is open on IOS. Please inspect the website as I am currently unable to supply the RAW html.

To replicate the issue, open the website ([Redec](https://www.redecindustrial.com/)) and click the menu item in the top right, and scroll down. You will notice that the background (body I think) also scrolls, and when you close the menu you are at the bottom of the page. I've looked everywhere and am unable to fix this problem.

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".x-btn-navbar").on("click", function() {
    $("html, body").toggleClass("noScroll");
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.noScroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    /* position: fixed */ 
}
```

Comment: Check if this SO question answers yours: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799970/how-to-disable-scroll-scrolling-on-ios-devices-ipad-iphone-mac-with-user-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799970/how-to-disable-scroll-scrolling-on-ios-devices-ipad-iphone-mac-with-user-c)

Comment: Unfortunately not as I only have 1 button to activate/deactivate scrolling, that code requires two :(