# used on a smartphone, shiny interactive plot doesn't understand finger movements

Tags: r, shiny, hover, click, smartphone

I have a R-Shiny application with a plot that implements interactive actions: click, hovering (hovering is passing the mouse over the plot, which can be detected by shiny). To give an idea, I post below a simplified shiny-app with the functionality that is problematic to me, the interactive drawing plot. (it's taken from an old answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48442522/3871924))

It's actually working fine, however I need people to use it from their **smartphones**. The problem: the finger movements we do in the smartphone are interpreted by the phone as *zooming* on the page or *scrolling* on the page, and not as mouse selection or mouse movement over the the plot (hovering).

Is there a modification of the code (java? CSS?) that I can implement on the app to turn touch events into mouse events, or an option/gesture on the smartphone to enable a mouse-like movement?

Thanks a lot; the code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  h4("Click on plot to start drawing, click again to pause"),
  sliderInput("mywidth", "width of the pencil", min=1, max=30, step=1, value=10),
  actionButton("reset", "reset"),
  plotOutput("plot", width = "500px", height = "500px",
             hover=hoverOpts(id = "hover", delay = 100, delayType = "throttle", clip = TRUE, nullOutside = TRUE),
             click="click"))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  vals = reactiveValues(x=NULL, y=NULL)
  draw = reactiveVal(FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$click, handlerExpr = {
    temp <- draw(); draw(!temp)
    if(!draw()) {
      vals$x <- c(vals$x, NA)
      vals$y <- c(vals$y, NA)
    }})
  observeEvent(input$reset, handlerExpr = {
    vals$x <- NULL; vals$y <- NULL
  })
  observeEvent(input$hover, {
    if (draw()) {
      vals$x <- c(vals$x, input$hover$x)
      vals$y <- c(vals$y, input$hover$y)
    }})
  output$plot= renderPlot({
    plot(x=vals$x, y=vals$y, xlim=c(0, 28), ylim=c(0, 28), ylab="y", xlab="x", type="l", lwd=input$mywidth)
  })}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: There is a [wishlist](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1858) for mobile interactions on GitHub regarding plotly.js (not the R api)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable panning/zoom gestures on the plot using the [`touch-action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action) CSS property:

```
#plot {
  touch-action: none;
}
```

Turning touch events into mouse events is a little trickier, but you could listen to touch events like `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend` and simulate equivalent mouse events in JavaScript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events and https://javascript.info/dispatch-events for more info.

It's not perfect, but I gave it a shot. I disabled touch gestures on the plot and added a script that converts `touchmove` to `mousemove`, and tells the server when to start drawing (on `touchstart`) and stop drawing (on `touchend`).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h4("Click on plot to start drawing, click again to pause"),
  sliderInput("mywidth", "width of the pencil", min=1, max=30, step=1, value=10),
  actionButton("reset", "reset"),
  plotOutput("plot", width = "400px", height = "400px",
             hover=hoverOpts(id = "hover", delay = 100, delayType = "throttle", clip = TRUE, nullOutside = TRUE),
             click="click"),
  tags$head(
    tags$script("
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var plot = document.getElementById('plot')

        plot.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
          var touch = e.changedTouches[0];
          var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent('mousemove', {
            view: window,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            screenX: touch.screenX,
            screenY: touch.screenY,
            clientX: touch.clientX,
            clientY: touch.clientY
          })
          touch.target.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
          e.preventDefault()
        }, { passive: false });

        plot.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
          Shiny.onInputChange('draw', true)
          e.preventDefault()
        }, { passive: false });

        plot.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
          Shiny.onInputChange('draw', false)
          e.preventDefault()
        }, { passive: false });
      })
    "),
    tags$style("#plot { touch-action: none; }")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  vals = reactiveValues(x=NULL, y=NULL)
  draw = reactiveVal(FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$click, {
    draw(!draw())
    vals$x <- append(vals$x, NA)
    vals$y <- append(vals$y, NA)
  })

  observeEvent(input$draw, {
    draw(input$draw)
    vals$x <- append(vals$x, NA)
    vals$y <- append(vals$y, NA)
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, handlerExpr = {
    vals$x <- NULL; vals$y <- NULL
  })

  observeEvent(input$hover, {
    if (draw()) {
      vals$x <- c(vals$x, input$hover$x)
      vals$y <- c(vals$y, input$hover$y)
    }
  })

  output$plot= renderPlot({
    plot(x=vals$x, y=vals$y, xlim=c(0, 28), ylim=c(0, 28), ylab="y", xlab="x", type="l", lwd=input$mywidth)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: published link with your code to test it: https://agenis.shinyapps.io/handwriting-v3/

Comment: Hi thanks, that's brilliant. I added some code in server to add NA in data.frame after touchend to break the lines (lift pencil). I also reduced a little the plot size so it will fit on most screens without scroll need. The blocking of the plot movements (panning/zoom) is not always effective on iphone/Safari, i find out that double clicking kind of works. Isn't there a way to block all zooming and scrolling on the whole webpage (without blocking the buttons...)? like arount this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/q/17596938/3871924

Comment: Ah shoot, of course Safari and iOS don't support `touch-action: none` :( https://caniuse.com/#search=touch-action. I can't really test this, but you could try adding `preventDefault()` to each touch event handler to disable scrolling/zooming completely. I edited the answer.

Comment: thanks.  Seems now that the page is not moving anymore, but side effect the actionbutton is disabled both in android and ios... Well, you helped enough on this, i will try myself to improve it now, thanks a lot!  This is the last version https://agenis.shinyapps.io/handwriting-v4/

Comment: Alright, one last try then. We could capture touch events on the plot only rather than the entire document. See the edit - I tested that it at least works on Android Chrome. If it still doesn't work on iOS, then sorry :/

Answer (score 6):

While I can't solve the question completely, maybe a dirty workaround could also have some value to you. Or someone else can build on that answer.

I could reproduce the error that the clicks on the plot are not captured on mobile. But I noticed that I can add additional clickevents with javascript/shinyjs.

One way would be:

```
  onevent(event = "click", id = "plot", function(e){
    global$clickx = c(global$clickx, e$pageX - 88)
    global$clicky = c(global$clicky, 540 - e$pageY)
  })
```

It has a few drawbacks:

- shapes are drawn with lines only, it does not capture all hovering on the plot
- the position is quite imprecise since you have to account for borders and margins (very dirty but potential here)

I ran a bit out of time after a few hours, one can for sure improve it, but maybe its of interest for you anyway.

**Test here:** (link might change within next weeks)

http://ec2-3-121-215-255.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/shiny/rstudio/sample-apps/mobile/

**Reproducible code:** (tested on smartphone: Mi A2)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  h4("Click on plot to start drawing, click again to pause"),

  plotOutput(outputId = "plot", width = "500px", height = "500px")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  onevent(event = "click", id = "plot", function(e){
    global$clickx = c(global$clickx, e$pageX - 88)
    global$clicky = c(global$clicky, 540 - e$pageY)
  })

  global <- reactiveValues(clickx = NULL, clicky = NULL)

  output$plot= renderPlot({
    plot(x = NULL, y = NULL, xlim=c(0, 440), ylim=c(0, 440), ylab="y", xlab="x", type="l")
    len <- length(global$clickx)
    lines(x = global$clickx, y = global$clicky, type = "p")      
    if(len > 1){
      for(nr in 2:len){
        lines(x = global$clickx[(nr - 1):nr], y = global$clicky[(nr - 1):nr], type = "l")
      }
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: hello thanks a lot for your answer; indeed I really need to solve this problem for a public demo. If I understand well, you replaced the hover by just the click? I havn't thought of this workaround, good idea, well it's a simplification because the drawing gets more difficult to draw, and less smooth. But if I don't have other solution i will go with this. I adapted your code to my initial app, with a button to "break" the line (lift the pencil) and an upgrade to show a point at right at the first click: https://agenis.shinyapps.io/handwriting-v2/

Comment: Well, I didn't really replace it. The original functionality does not seem to work on mobile, therefore I removed it. If you get it to work it would be the better solution, but I am no mobile expert. Therefote I just added another click event. I am not sure how to capture hovering on mobile, it would be mousedown I guess, but on mouse down I get a contextmenu but it didn't manage to prevent the default behaviour.

Comment: I had another answer that solved the original problem so i awarded the bounty to him. Thanks anyway @BigDataScientist for your contribution and your precious time!

Comment: totally deserved. I am very interested to dig into his answer after work. I have not much experience with mobile and am excited to learn how he solved it :).